# Collision and changing the scene. C#

Tags: unity, c#, collision-detection

I'm running into a problem where I want to create some code that such that if an object (Cube) is destroyed, it to changes to another scene.

Here is my code:

```
public class Move : MonoBehaviour {

    void playerWalk()
    {
        var x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * 150.0f;
        var z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * 3.0f;

        transform.Rotate(0, x, 0);
        transform.Translate(0, 0, z);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.name == "Cube")
            Destroy(col.gameObject);    
    }

    void Update () 
    {
        playerWalk();
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.B))
            print("hello");
    }
}
```

What do do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

You use `using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;` and the after the `Destroy(col.gameObject);` just put below `SceneManager.LoadScene("SceneName");`

```
if (col.gameObject.name == "Cube")
{
        Destroy(col.gameObject);
}
if(col.gameObject == null)
{
        SceneManager.LoadScene("SceneName");
}
```

Comment: Why the second `if` block, rather than putting the load command in the same block after the `Destroy`?

Comment: Just my habit though just making things sure.. but you're right.

Comment: In fact, the second if statement will *always* be true, since if the `gameObject` was null the if statement above would throw a null pointer exception (or whatever it is called in C#).

Comment: @Charanor - Null Reference Exception

Comment: Thank you very much. I do not need this yet but will do when I need to create levels. You saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 1):

Unity has a special set of methods for using *triggers* as an event to handle logic like this. You are 99% there, but instead of `OnCollisionEnter` use `OnTriggerEnter`, though in your collider on the object set the `IsTrigger` to true.

```
import Unity.SceneManagement;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour {

    void playerWalk()
    {
        var x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * 150.0f;
        var z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * 3.0f;

        transform.Rotate(0, x, 0);
        transform.Translate(0, 0, z);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.name == "Cube") {
            Destroy(col.gameObject);   
            SceneManagemer.LoadScene("YourSceneName"); 
         }
    }

    void Update () 
    {
        playerWalk();
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.B))
            print("hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me, I will keep this in mind when tackling my level progression mechanic!